# Display Prev and Current value based on a ID - SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am not sure if a similar question has been posted. I was unable to find one.

I have the following table:

[image]

What I trying to get is the below:

[image]

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Comment: What if there are 3 records for id `1234`, what would be the result?

Comment: If there are 3 records , it should display the first one as Prev1, second one as Prev2 and third one as current.

Comment: @PamPetronas Are you saying the more records per ID, the more columns in the output?

Comment: Yes, Hans. That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Worked both in Oracle and Snowflake:

```
SELECT t.ID,
    t.prev_dt,
    t.current_dt,
    t.prev_code,
    t.curr_code 
FROM (
    SELECT id,
        order_dt,
        LAG(order_dt, 1) OVER (PARTITION by id ORDER BY id, order_dt) prev_dt,
        upd_dt current_dt,
        LAG(code, 1) OVER (PARTITION by id ORDER BY id, upd_dt) prev_code,
        code curr_code
    FROM t111
) t 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id,
        MAX(order_dt) max_date 
    FROM t111 
    GROUP BY id
) idm
  ON idm.id=t.id AND t.order_dt=idm.max_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want window function `lag()`:

```
select 
    id,
    lag(order_dt) over(partition by id order by order_by_id) prev_dt,
    order_dt current_dt,
    lag(code) over(partition by id order by order_by_id) prev_code,
    code curr_code
from mytable
```

Note that the above query does not filter the records of the table. When there is no preceeding record, `lag()` returns `null`. If you want to filter out the first record per group, and assuming that such record is identify by `order_by_id = 1`, you can do:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        id,
        lag(order_dt) over(partition by id order by order_by_id) prev_dt,
        order_dt current_dt,
        lag(code) over(partition by id order by order_by_id) prev_code,
        code curr_code,
        order_by_id
    from mytable
) t
where order_by_id > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Window functions might be the best approach.  But you could also use `join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.order_dt as prev_dt, t2.upd_dt as curr_date,
       t1.code as prev_code, t2.code as curr_code
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.order_by_id = 1 and t2.order_by_id = 2;
```

In Snowflake, I simply do not know whether this would have better, worse, or similar performance to using window functions.